# Array .map() returning undefined

Tags: arrays, angular, chart.js

This is the structure of the array when I `console.log` it.

```
-[]
  -0: Array(31)
    -0:
      -date: "2018-08-26T00:00:00-04:00"
      -registered:
        -standard: 0
        -vip: 0
      -waitlisted:
        -standard: 0
        -vip: 0
```

This is my code to map the date and the registered (two separate arrays):

```
this.data.map((value) => value.date);
this.data.map((value) => value.registered['standard']);
```

I either get an empty array or `undefined` when I log these. What am I doing wrong?

I want to use these for a chart using ChartJS where:

```
this.lineChart = new Chart(lineCtx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: (I want the dates to be the labels),
      data: (I want the list of standard registrants)
    }]...
```

EDIT:

I've updated the way I get the data to show the following structure:

```
{
  "registrationHistory": [{
    "date": "2018-08-26T00:00:00-4:00",
    "registered": {
      "vip":0,
      "standard":0
    },
    "waitlisted":{
      "vip":0,
      "standard":0
  }
  {
   ,...
  }
]}
```

Comment: Please add the complete array, do `console.log()` on that array and provide that in your question.

Comment: Tip: you can also share your array easily if you do JSON.stringify(data), where data is your array.

Comment: The array has 31 objects in it, I'm not sure how you would like me to display that here.

Answer (score 1):

Your array is two-dimensional and `map` is iterating only the first dimension, i.e:

```
-[]
  -0: Array(31)     // first dimension
    -0:             // second dimension
      -date: "2018-08-26T00:00:00-04:00"
      ...
```

This would look like the following JSON string:

```
[[{"date":"2018-08-26T00:00:00-04:00", ...}]]
```

Since you haven't provided a full example it's impossible to recommend the most applicable solution:

- If you control the data source, remove the first dimension since it appears redundant.
- Assuming you only want the first element of the first dimension, refer to that key:

  ```
  this.data[0].map((value) => value.date);
  ```

If your data model is more complex than revealed in your question you'll need to figure out another approach.

Comment: @brettwbyron Did this answer your question?